# Irreducible Polynomial for $GF(2^{256})$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I'm looking for a pattern to generate Galois Field multiplication for $2^{256}$ binary value. So far I have come up with a patter as follows;

$$
1 \rightarrow 1 \\
x \rightarrow x \\
x^2\rightarrow x^2\\
...\\
x^{256} \rightarrow x + 1
$$

Is it $x + 1$ for $x^{256}$?
If so, for $x^{257} \rightarrow (x^2 + x)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The polynomial $p(x)=x^{256}+x+1$ cannot be irreducible. For if $\alpha$ is a zero, then $\alpha^{256}=\alpha+1$ implying that $\alpha^{256^2}=(\alpha+1)^{256}=\alpha^{256}+1^{256}=\alpha$. As $256^2=2^{16}$ this means that $\alpha\in GF(2^{16})$.

Comment: You need to find an irreducible polynomial (possibly a primitive one, but I can't really see anyone building and using a discrete log table for a field this large). I would also consider trying to find a (near optimal) normal basis for doing arithmetic in this field. Does the algorithm in *Handbook of (applied?) Cryptography* help you?

Comment: Programs for computing primitive polynomials: http://seanerikoconnor.freeservers.com/Mathematics/AbstractAlgebra/PrimitivePolynomials/overview.html

Answer (score 3):

See Miodrag Zivkovic, [A Table of Primitive Binary Polynomials](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~ezivkovm/publications/primpol1.pdf). The example $x^{256}+x^{241}+x^{178}+x^{121}+1$ is given for the field of size $2^{256}$.

Comment: \*Živković *[Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?]*