# What is the Conway polynomial for $GF(2^{256})$?

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Frank Luebeck's database of Conway Polynomials seems to be missing an entry for the 256-bit field, $\mathbb{F}_{2^{256}}$; neither [his hosted copy](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EFrank.Luebeck/data/ConwayPol/CP2.html#:%7E:text=f2%2C257) nor [sagemath's internal copy](https://github.com/sagemath/conway-polynomials/blob/0.8/src/conway_polynomials/CPimport.txt#L143) has it.

While there have been found irreducible polynomials for this field (such as $X^{256}+X^{10}+X^5+X^2+1$ [by Bill Buchanan](https://asecuritysite.com/gf/fer#:%7E:text=an-,irreducible%20polynomial,.,-This) and $X^{256}+X^{241}+X^{178}+X^{121}+1$ [by Miodrag Živković](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2843587/188128)), I couldn't find any source that claimed to have found the *lexographically lowest* such polynomial.

Has it been found? If so, what is it? If not, were there any obstacles to finding it, or was it just an issue of (lack of) interest/need? I couldn't find anything about attempts, even.

Answer (score 2):

When I saw how low the one Buchanan found was ($X^{256} + X^{10} + \dots$), and thought about that possibly being an upper-bound (if that one happens to be primitive, then worst-case $2^{10}$ attempts isn't that big of a number), I figured I'd try brute-forcing it, just to see if I'd get anywhere. With such a small pile of numbers to search, Sagemath handles it in just a couple of seconds!

The result: $X^{256} + X^{10} + X^5 + X^2 + 1$ is the Conway Polynomial for ${GF}{({2^{256}})}$.

---

Appendix: code

```
# Tested on Sage version 10.1, CPython version 3.10.12

R.<X> = GF(2)[]

for p in R.polynomials(of_degree=256):
    if p.is_irreducible():
        print('\u0007')
        print(p)
        if p.is_primitive():
            print("Primitive.")
            break
        else:
            print("Not primitive")
    print('.', end='')
```

Comment: I, too, thought that going from Buchanan's polynomial downwards should be a piece of cake with suitable software. But did you check primitivity also? IIRC a Conway polynomial need to be primitive also. Brute forcing that could still be doable, as the integer factorization of $2^{256}-1$ is known.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Good catch. (Sadly, it looks like SymPy's `Poly.is_primitive` is **not** right, here; so I had to go figure out Sage.) Interestingly, the polynomial is correct, despite my originally incorrect method of finding it.